# Are people who light those candles (votive candles) supposed to take a vow?

Tags: catholicism, tradition

In Catholic Churches we light votive candles. I have never really understood what "votive" refers to. Are people who light those candles supposed to take a vow?

Comment: *Are people who light those candles supposed to take a vow ?* - No. A [votive offering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Votive_offering), as they are called, is a token of a previous vow, usually promising God and/or one of His saints that, if helped with a certain predicament, the receiver will offer, in return, as a sign of gratitude, a gift to the church; see also [tama(ta)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tama_(votive)) and [Biertan donarium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biertan_Donarium).

Answer (score 1):

In Catholicism, a [votive candle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Votive_candle) signifies literally that the lighting is done in fulfillment of a vow (Latin, votum), although in most cases the intention is merely to give honor and to seek help from the saint before whose images the candle is lit.

Roman pagan culture used candles in religious practice. Lit candles were used in religious and military processions, showing the divine presence, aid, or favor of the gods. With the development of emperor worship, candles were also lit near his image as a sign of respect and reverence. The emperor was considered divine and even given the titles *Pontifex Maximus* (High Priest) and *Dominus et Deus* (Lord and God).

Christians adapted the use of lit candles (or even oil lamps in the Eastern Roman Empire) for Mass, liturgical processions, evening prayer ceremonies, funeral processions, and to show reverence.

Answer (score 0):

**Are people who light those candles (votive candles) supposed to take a vow?**

Some Catholics may do so; but the vast majority do not.

Votive candles are sometimes seen as the same concept lines as an [ex-voto](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex-voto), but not always. For most Catholics it merely signifies the intention is merely to give honor and to seek help from the saint before whose images the candle is lit.

> A [**votive candle**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Votive_candle) or prayer candle is a small candle, typically white or beeswax yellow, intended to be burnt as a votive offering in an act of Christian prayer, especially within the Anglican, Lutheran, and Roman Catholic Christian denominations, among others. In Christianity, votive candles are commonplace in many churches, as well as home altars, and symbolize the "prayers the worshipper is offering for him or herself, or for other people."
>
> **Use by Christian denomination**
>
> Candles are lit for prayer intentions. To "light a candle for someone" indicates one's intention to say a prayer for another person, and the candle symbolizes that prayer. Many times, "a board is placed nearby with names of those for whom prayer is requested." A donation box is usually placed near a votive candle rack in order that Christians lighting the votive candles can help defray the cost of votive candles, and make a votive offering to the church.
>
> **Catholicism**
>
> In the Roman Catholic Church, candles are at times placed before a statue of Jesus, of the Blessed Virgin Mary, or of some other saint. Often, in older or traditional churches, this will be before a side-altar.
>
> A votive candle signifies literally that the lighting is done in fulfillment of a vow (Latin, votum), **although in most cases the intention is merely to give honor and to seek help from the saint before whose images the candle is lit.**
>
> Candles used may vary from long, taper-type candles to tealight candles. Tealight candles are either placed in holders or just on a platform in front of the statue. Long candles may be placed in a special holder.

The [Catholic Encyclopedia](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/03246a.htm)has the following to say about candles:

> Candles were, and are, commonly used to burn before shrines towards which the faithful wish to show special devotion. The candle burning its life out before a statue is no doubt felt in some ill-defined way to be symbolical of prayer and sacrifice. A curious medieval practice was that of offering at any favoured shrine a candle or a number of candles equalling in measurement the height of the persons for whom some favour was asked. This was called "measuring to" such or such a saint. The practice can be traced back to the time of St. Radegund (d. 587) and later right through the Middle Ages. It was especially common in England and the North of France in the twelfth and thirteenth centuries.